# How to correctly provide password to PostgreSQL when connecting remotely in Windows?

Tags: postgresql

DB: PostgreSQL 9.0
Client: Windows 7
Server Windows 2008, 64bit

I'm trying to connect remotely to a PostgreSQL instance for purposes of performing a pg_dump to my local machine.

Everything works from my client machine, except that I need to provide a password at the password prompt, and I'd ultimately like to batch this with a script.

I've followed the instructions here:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgpass.html

But it's not working.

To recap, I've created a file on the server: `C:/Users/postgres/AppData/postgresql/pgpass.conf`, where PostgreSQL is the db user.

The file has one line with the following data:

```
\*:5432:\*postgres:[mypassword]
```

I've also tried replacing each `*` with `[localhost|myip]` and `[mydatabasename]` respectively.

From my client machine, I connect using:

```
pg_dump -h <myip> -U postgres -w [mydbname] > [mylocaldumpfile]
```

I'm presuming that I need to provide the `-w` switch in order to ignore password prompt, at which point it should look in the AppData directory on the server.

It just comes back with:

> connection to database failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied.

As a hack workaround, if there was a way I could tell the Windows batch file on my client machine to inject the password at the PostgreSQL prompt, that would work as well.

Comment: `-h` is for the host to connect to, yours is empty. The first four fields in the `pgpass` file should be either literal values or *, yours is a mix. The `pgpass` file should reside on the client machine in the `AppData` folder of the user who issues the `pg_dump` command - yours is on the server.

Comment: Empty -h is a typo.  I've tried all '*', no '*' and every combination in between.  I've also tried with a local AppData file, but same issue.

Comment: What are the permissions on the .pgpass file?  They need to be readable by the user only.

Comment: Is pg_hba.conf configured correctly?

Comment: pg_hba is configured correctly, as I am able to remotely log-in and backup if I set the method to trust.  pgpass file permissions are granted to the user.

Answer (score 16):

It works for me:

Use command line

```
cd %appdata%
mkdir postgresql
cd postgresql
notepad pgpass.conf
```

inside pgpass.conf paste your connection string (`*:5432:*postgres:[mypassword]`) and save the file.
To connect to postgres use:

```
psql/pg_dump -U <username> -h <host> -w <other params you want to use>
```

Comment: Jeez.. it was in `\Roaming`, I was using it in `\Local`. Thanks.

Comment: shouldn't the connection string be \*:5432:\*:postgres:[mypassword] (colon after second *). As per https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/libpq-pgpass.html , the format is hostname:port:database:username:password

Answer (score 7):

I have solved similar problem (only in Linux) to use ip address in pgpass and psql.

.pgpass

```
127.0.0.1:5432:db:dbuser:123
```

psql params

```
psql -d db -U dbuser -h 127.0.0.1 -w
```

pg_hba conf with default settings:

```
# IPv4 local connections:
84 host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          md5
```

Comment: The same exact thing happened to me with 9.3 on Windows.  Changing host to 127.0.0.1 fixed it.

Answer (score 7):

**Create pgpass.conf file**

```
Windows > Start > Run
type %APPDATA%
press OK
Create a folder: postgresql
Create a file  : pgpass.conf   (under postgresql folder)
```

**Open pgpass.conf file**

Now you should have below file ready, open it via below (making sure it exists):

```
Windows > Start > Run
type %APPDATA%\postgresql\pgpass.conf
press OK
```

**Paste pgpass.conf file contents**

Paste the below

```
# serverDomainOrIP:PORT:databaseName:userName:password
# 127.0.0.1:5432:myDbName:postgres:myPassword
# *:5432:*:*:myPassword
```

You can do one of the below:
- Remove # for the 3rd line, and give your password in the place of "myPassword"
OR
- Remove # for the 2nd line, and give ip (or, yourDomain.com), dbname, username & password

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 6):

I've had a similar problem which I didn't manage to resolve - I couldn't get the script to recognise the pgpass.conf file. I however used a work-around of setting the PGPASSWORD environment variable in the batch file I was using (PostgreSQL 9.6).

Inside a batch file:

`SET PGPASSWORD=<<password>>
pg_dump.exe -h <<host>> -p <<port>> -U <<user>> -Fc -b -v -f <<output file path>> <<database>>`

Comment: worked for me on windows 10 with local copy of bin directory to run only pg_dump.exe file against remote DB.

Answer (score 5):

I have gotten it to work with the following:

pgpass.conf:

```
127.0.0.1:5432:*:username:password
```

However, I have it stored here:

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\postgresql
```

For some reason, on a previous iteration of Postgres, the database had generated the `pgpass` file and stored it there. I was running into the same issue you were having, moved it to that directory and it worked. I'm not sure why though.

Then, all you'll need to do is:

```
pg_dump -h myip mydb > mylocaldumpfile
```

...ensuring that `myip` and the ip in `pgpass.conf` are identical. If they are not, it will prompt you for a password.

Answer (score 0):

You could use pgAdmin III to store the password (in the server's properties). 
That operation automatically creates a correct pgpass.conf file. You can then schedule a task to run a simple batch file that would read:

`"C:\path\to\pg_dump.exe" -U <user> -w <database> > C:\path\to\database.backup`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are logged in as the user corresponding with the folder where the pgpass.conf file lives.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using UTF-8 encoding, please ensure that you are using **without BOM** mode.

Otherwise leave the first line as a comment:

```
# This line may contain hidden BOM bytes
localhost:5432:database:username:password
```

Also you don't need to escape asterisks `\*`, just put `*` to enable wildcard matching.